# Do work jdk 7 with sdk and eclipse 64bit?

Tags: android, sdk, java

I have a problem with eclipse. There are two situations:

1- Install JDK6 and SDK and I can run sdk manager but I can not run eclipse

2- Install JDK7 and SDK and I can run eclipse but I can't run SDK manager

Comment: The android tools don't work with a JDK7 according to the official docs. So stick with JDK6 to be on the safe side. Why eclipse doesn't run with that can't really be answered though. You have to provide more information: Do you get an error message? What eclipse version are you using? Which OS do you use?

Comment: I use win7 64 bit on vmware,and eclipse 64 bit,but sdk is not run,as i click on sdk icon ,then is not working and do not any error

Answer (score 0):

Just install both JDKs and select the best working for Eclipse and Android SDK.

For Eclipse you can specify the VM to be used in `Eclipse.ini`. Just add the following two line at the beguinning:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin
```

In Eclipse register both JDKs as Java Runtimes and give them appropriate names so that you cans elect the correct one for your Android project.

Comment: SDK manager don't have to started from within Eclipse. Just execute it manually. This works fine with Java7.